# create new function object from a function within a function [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

currently I have to support the `IE 9` so I cannot use classes and lambda expressions.

I have a function that represents my class and within this function I have another function for creating a new object.

For the scope I have to work with `this` but the problem is, there is no

- `new this.Obj()`
- `this.Obj()`
- `this new Obj()`
- `new (this.Obj())`

This is what I tried so far. I created a small example

```js
function Store(originDogs) {

  this.Dog = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  this.originDogs = originDogs;

  this.dogs = this.originDogs.map(function(x) {
    return new this.Dog(x.name);
  });
}

new Store([{
  name: "dog1"
}, {
  name: "dog2"
}, {
  name: "dog3"
}]);
```

The error I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: this.Dog is not a constructor

How do I have to Setup `new this.Dog` to make it work?

Comment: "I have to support the IE 9" — It has been over two & a half years since IE9 reached end of life and Microsoft stopped providing security fixes for it. It needs removing from whatever organisation you are supporting.

Comment: @ChrisG — The question explicitly ruled arrow functions out due to lack of support in IE9.

Comment: The function passed to map hijacks `this`; a common solution is using `var that = this;`, then using `that.Dog()` inside it.